# Adding child element with attributes to XML using System.XML

Tags: c#, xml, system.xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<testsuite name="Tests" rxversion="5.4.5.19886" id="d1203701-d61c-4ae6-932d-faa44beb925a" reportfilename="%S_%Y%M%D_%T.rxlog" reporttemplatefolder="" reportxslfilename="" placescreenshotsinfolder="True" ReportTime="RelativeToTestSuiteStartTime" reportwriteinterval="30000ms" reportcompress="False" enabletracingscreenshots="True" TracingScreenshotMode="Foreground" TracingScreenshotQuality="40" reportlevel="Info;20" warnunboundvariables="False">
<testconfigurations default="TestRun">
    <testconfiguration name="TestRun" />
</testconfigurations>
</testsuite>
```

And the following code to update the XML:

```
var xe = new XmlDocument();
xe.Load("Z:\\Tests\\Tests.rxtst");

string testconfig = "//testsuite/testconfigurations/testconfiguration";
string testconfigend = "//testsuite";

XmlNode tc = xe.SelectSingleNode(testconfig);
XmlNode tcend = xe.SelectSingleNode(testconfigend);

XmlElement xs = xe.CreateElement("testcase");
xs.SetAttribute("id", "450c9a87-75dc-4538-bc2c-6df6eb359d2a");
XmlNode par = tc.ParentNode;
par.InsertBefore(xs, tc.LastChild);

xe.Save("st.rxtst");
```

Using this code I get the following output of the xml:

```
<testsuite name="Tests" rxversion="5.4.5.19886" id="d1203701-d61c-4ae6-932d-faa44beb925a" reportfilename="%S_%Y%M%D_%T.rxlog" reporttemplatefolder="" reportxslfilename="" placescreenshotsinfolder="True" ReportTime="RelativeToTestSuiteStartTime" reportwriteinterval="30000ms" reportcompress="False" enabletracingscreenshots="True" TracingScreenshotMode="Foreground" TracingScreenshotQuality="40" reportlevel="Info;20" warnunboundvariables="False">
    <testconfigurations default="TestRun">
        <testconfiguration name="TestRun" />
        <testcase id="450c9a87-75dc-4538-bc2c-6df6eb359d2a" />
    </testconfigurations>
</testsuite>
```

I want to add the `testcase` element as a child of `testconfiguration`. The output should be like:

```
<testsuite name="Tests" rxversion="5.4.5.19886" id="d1203701-d61c-4ae6-932d-faa44beb925a" reportfilename="%S_%Y%M%D_%T.rxlog" reporttemplatefolder="" reportxslfilename="" placescreenshotsinfolder="True" ReportTime="RelativeToTestSuiteStartTime" reportwriteinterval="30000ms" reportcompress="False" enabletracingscreenshots="True" TracingScreenshotMode="Foreground" TracingScreenshotQuality="40" reportlevel="Info;20" warnunboundvariables="False">
    <testconfigurations default="TestRun">
        <testconfiguration name="TestRun">
            <testcase id="450c9a87-75dc-4538-bc2c-6df6eb359d2a"/>
        </testconfiguration>
    </testconfigurations>
</testsuite>
```

How can I add the `testcase` element as a child of `testconfiguration`?

**Update**
The `id` is now correctly set but the element is not added as a child of `testconfiguration` node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `XmlElement.SetAttribute` to add an attribute to the element, setting value to `XmlElement.InnerText` replaces the nested content.

```
xs .SetAttribute("id", "450c9a87-75dc-4538-bc2c-6df6eb359d2a");
```

Alternatively you could use `Linq` to `Xml` as well.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

foreach(var element in doc.Descendants("testconfiguration"))
{
    element.Add(new XElement("testcase", new XAttribute("id","450c9a87-75dc-4538-bc2c-6df6eb359d2a") ));
}
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yRXBGb)

Comment: The `id` is now correctly set but the element is not added as a child of `testconfiguration`. Thanks for your suggestion.